# How to get exported function names from a .dll(system)?

Tags: dll, export, portable-executable

I want the exported function namelist (by name and by ordinal) from a DLL. I got the function names(exported by name) using export directory table,but I can't retrieve the exported function list, which exported by ordinals.

Please help me to retrieve it. I also tried .lib of that dll, there is also, displays NONAME. thanks in advance to legends

Answer (score 1):

If You know dll name ,You can view through many tools (**pe explorer,CFF Explorer**),Here all exported function names  are viewable with ordinal .Another one way from microsoft (**dumpbin.exe**) its a command line tool ..its also list out all exported fn names

Answer (score 0):

If you have mingw32 installed, simply run

nm.exe *your_dll*

Where your_dll is the dll you want to to get the ordinals and exports of.
nm.exe should be in the bin directory of your mingw32 installation.

Comment: Mingw32 is the Windows port of the unix compiler, GCC. You can get it at http://mingw.org/category/wiki/download